# Using indexOf but with a member of the class contained in the List

Tags: java, collections

I was wondering something. If I have a class like this:

```
public class OrderItem {
    private Item item;
    private int quantity;
    private BigDecimal total;
}
```

And I have in the class `Chart` a `List<OrderItem> orders`. `OrderItem` is identified by its `item` so I was thinking if there is a method of `orders` I can ovveride (maybe `indexOf`) to check if an `OrderItem` exists and then **retrieve** it (or its index)

I'm talking about something different from using a `for` loop and check its item. Maybe an interface?

**edit**: I'm sorry I mislead the question, I forgot an important part. I need to retrieve the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over-ride `.equals()` and `.hashcode()` in `OrderItem` so equality is determined by `item`.

You can then call `indexOf(dummyOrderItem)`, where dummyOrderItem is a dummy object created with the correct `item`. You can then call get(index) to retrieve the true object.

If you use Eclipse, you can generate these methods automatically using `source->generate hashCode() and equals()`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((item == null) ? 0 : item.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    OrderItem other = (OrderItem) obj;
    if (item == null)
    {
        if (other.item != null)
            return false;
    }
    else if (!item.equals(other.item))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I realize now my question is not correct. After I check if it exists, I need to retrieve it.

Comment: You could use the same technique, but call List.indexOf() with a dummy object that has the correct item. Then call get(index).

Comment: @dierre Both these answers are still pertinent. Just use `indexOf` instead of `contains` and the list will return the first index of the object you are looking for (or -1).

Comment: Actually that sounds right. If you edit your question,I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method of `List` if you override the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method of `OrderItem`

From the documentation for `contains()`:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Within your override of `equals`, compare your `Item`s and return true/false as appropriate. If you override `equals()`, you should also override `hashcode()`.

EDIT: in response to comment, the above applies to [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) too - once you implement `equals()`, index of will also work in the same manner as `contains()`. Just provide to it an instance of `OrderItem` containing the same `Item`, and you'll get back the index in the list of the matching `OrderItem` (if any), which can then be used to access it.

Comment: I realize now my question is not correct. After I check if it exists, I need to retrieve it.